# Are decision forests and random forests the same thing?

Tags: random-forest

[Based on an answer on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124/statistical-classification-of-text/143#143) I've been looking into implementing a [random forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) in .NET/C# to classify documents of text.

Looking around the web to see if there are existing implementations, I came across an algorithm for a [decision forest on Alglib](http://www.alglib.net/dataanalysis/decisionforest.php).

The thing is, I can't seem to find anything specific to "decision forest" anywhere (it's ambiguous [even here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=decision%20forest)), it's typically mixed in with random forest.

That said, are the two the same, just being referenced differently, or are there inherent differences between the two?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the [Alglib page](http://www.alglib.net/dataanalysis/decisionforest.php) you cited, it says,

> "The RDF [Random decision forest] algorithm is a modification of the
>   original Random Forest algorithm designed by Leo Breiman and Adele
>   Cutler."

[A question at rapid-i.com](http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php?topic=2996.0) refers to

> Ho TK (1998) The Random Subspace Method for Constructing Decision
>   Forests. IEEE Trans Pattern Anal Mach Intel 20(8) 832-844 [[Abstract](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/34.709601)]

which might be yet another thing.

[At Breiman's web page at Berkeley](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm), it says,

> "Random Forests(tm) is a trademark of Leo Breiman and Adele Cutler and
>   is licensed exclusively to Salford Systems for the commercial release
>   of the software. Our trademarks also include RF(tm),
>   RandomForests(tm), RandomForest(tm) and Random Forest(tm)."

So I conclude that there are subtle differences, but mostly it's a trademark issue regarding the name "random forest".